# What is a runtime-constraint?

Tags: c, function, runtime, terminology, function-call

I've heard of the term "runtime-constraint" many times. I have been looking for the term "runtime-constraint" in the actual standard ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18), but all that I have found is:

Source: ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18), Section 3.18:

> 3.18
>
> 1 runtime-constraint
>
> requirement on a program when calling a library function.

I do not understand, what this sentence shall do express. Which requirement? I understand less than before.

The "requirement" itself is not described here in any way. It is only emphasized, that the cited requirement shall be extant when calling a library function, but not what this requirement exactly is.

And what is meant here by "program" exactly?

Is it meant, that a runtime-constraint is a requirement on an executable file *how* a library function shall be invoked? But why shall the executable file call a library function? My point of it was that the executable file is only machine-code, which needs to be executed.

---

- What is a runtime-constraint in C?

  ---

Comment: Runtime constraints are documented for the optional bounds-checking interfaces described in Annex K.

Comment: A runtime-constraint applies to the _execution_ of the program. As mentioned in NOTE 1, a runtime-constraint need not be diagnosed at translation time. As mentioned in NOTE 2, the functions in annex K are required to verify that the runtime-constraints they specify are not violated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a check made at runtime for illegal or missing values - the actual constraint check depends on the specific library function being called.  For example,

> **K.3.5.1.1 The tmpfile_s function**
> Synopsis
>
> 1 `#define _ _STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_ _ 1
> #include <stdio.h>
> errno_t tmpfile_s(FILE * restrict * restrict streamptr);`
> **Runtime-constraints**
> 2 `streamptr` shall not be a null pointer.

IOW, if you pass `NULL` for `streamptr`, that's a runtime constraint violation, which causes a constraint-handler function to be called (you can write your own constraint handler functions).  It's kind-of-sort-of-but-not-really an exception handler, if that helps visualize it.

Each library function defines its own requirements, so each has its own runtime constraint check(s).

**Edit**

As Jonathan Leffler points out in the comments, runtime constraints only apply to the bounds-checking library functions specified in Annex K, and those library functions are optional — not every implementation supports them.  Indeed, the C standard committee paper [n1967](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm) indicates that no implementation supports them completely, and the functions specified in the C11 and C18 Annex K may be removed from a future version of the C standard.

Comment: You might also note that the runtime constraints are only specified explicitly for the functions in Annex K, which is an optional part of the standard.  The only prior mentions of runtime constraints are in the §3.18 definition.  There's a general set of rules for the use of functions in C11 [§7.1.4 Use of library functions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4), with individual functions able to override specific rules.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Annex K is the key element, which provides the rationale I was missing. The sentence shall, in my humble opinion, be revised to "requirement on a program when calling a library function *designated in Annex K*" to avoid the confusion, which was happen to me. Annex K also explains the context of runtime-constraints more clearly.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica — it is more likely, I think, that the definition will be dropped along with Annex K.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I agree.